# How to apply .editable() to dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage that executes this javascript on $(document).ready().  The .editable() comes from the [X-Editable javascript library](http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/) (in place editing).

```
$('tr td:nth-child(2) a').editable();
```

A link/button on my page allows for the addition of rows to the table.  Is there a way to perform editable() on just the new  instead of using the same selector as before and having it fetch all the matches again?

```
$('#newCriteria').click(function () {
    var id = 0;

    // load template
    var cTemplate = $('#criteriaTemplate').html();

    // fill template
    var template = cTemplate.format(id, 'New Field');

    // attach editable (doesnt work)
    $('tr td:nth-child(2) a', template).editable();

    // append to table
    $('#criteriaTable').append(template);
});
```

As you can see, I thought I'd try and pass the template html through as a context to the jQuery but since it isn't actually part of the DOM until I append it, it doesn't work.

Another possible solution is that I could just modify the selector to `'tr:last-child td:nth-child(2) a'`.

I was wondering if there was some why to use .on() on the  element to have jQuery automatically add the handlers for me.  I've only ever used .on() in the past to add handlers like `.on('click', '...', function() {})`, I don't know if it can be used for things like editable().

The template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="criteriaTemplate">
        <tr data-criteriaID='{0}'>
            <td><i class="icon-remove" /></td>
            <td><a href="#">{1}</a></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-value="0">String</a></td>
        </tr>
    </script>
```

Comment: What if you try to run your `.editable()` line *after* your `.append(template)` line?

Comment: @Ian The whole reason I didn't do that was that I wanted to get only the `<tr>` I just added, not every `<tr>` in the table.

Comment: Literally just trying switching your last two statements. Run this: `$('#criteriaTable').append(template); $('tr td:nth-child(2) a', template).editable();`. I'm thinking the row might need to be in the DOM before you can call `editable()` on it

Comment: No good.  It was worth a shot, but I think because template wasn't fetched using $(), it won't work.

Comment: Wait, what exactly does `$('#criteriaTemplate').html()` return? Is it a `<tr></tr>` with stuff inside it? If so, I think the selector you want is: `$('td:nth-child(2) a', template)` to call `editable()` on

Comment: @Ian I'll add it to the question, but yes it is a <tr>.  And removing <tr> from the selector did not work.

Comment: How about adding an ID to the content before you append it? Then you can select the newly appended content with that ID, do your stuff and then remove the ID.

Answer (score 2):

x-editable has a `selector` option, so you can apply `.editable` to table tag:

```
$('#table').editable({
  ...
  selector: 'tr td:nth-child(2) a'
});
```